# Checking each value in list with each other

Tags: algorithm, list, ocaml, ml

I am working with OCaml and I have a list where I need to check all elements in a list with each other. The list is a list of units, either base or derived units. Base units are m,s,g and derived units are any units that use m,s,g such as kg, min, ft, lb, etc.

So an example list would be [lb; ft; m]. This list would be invalid because ft and m share the same base unit: m. To be more clear [lb; kg; s] will be invalid because lb and kg share the same base unit:m. However [ft; s; m] is completely valid. These base unit conversions are kept in a hash for lookup.

My problem is how could I check all the units with each other. I've tried using folds but it's making my head hurt. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you clarify how "lb" and "kg" share the same base unit, "m"? Assuming I'm reading you correctly, "m", "s" and "g" stand for "metre", "second" and "gram", respectively. Also, is this homework? If so, it's considered nice to tag your question so.

Comment: So, as I understand it, you want to check whether any two *consecutive* elements meets some condition (shares base units)?

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution with quadratic complexity:

```
(* [check_pair] should return [false] if check fails *)
let rec check_each_pair check_pair = function
  | [] -> true
  | hd1 :: rest ->
    let rec check_rest = function
      | [] -> true
      | hd2 :: rest -> check_pair hd1 hd2 && check_rest rest
    in
    check_rest rest && check_each_pair check_pair rest
```

Remark that the inner `check_rest` is only checking a predicate on each element of the list. That's `List.for_all`.

```
let rec check_each_pair check_pair = function
  | [] -> true
  | hd1 :: rest ->
    List.for_all (check_pair hd1) rest && check_each_pair check_pair rest
```

You could go combinator-crazy and also implement `check_each_pair` as a call to a recursion combinator, but that's not direct (you need to accumulate `rest` somehow, so a fold, but then you want the shortcut fail-early semantics...) and I don't see any advantage.

Comment: My Haskell instinct is suggesting me some List.(concat map)-ping! :D

Comment: This is where `inits` and `tails` come handy: `check_each_pair prd = all (\(h:t) -> all (prd h) t) . tails` or some such.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a list of all pairs from a list first (by using [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the list with itself) and check the condition on the list of pairs later:

```
let cartesian xs ys =
    List.concat (List.map (fun x -> List.map (fun y -> (x, y)) ys) xs)

let haveDifferentBases(x, x') =
   (* check whether they have different base units *)

let check_all_pairs xs =
   List.for_all haveDifferentBases (cartesian xs xs)
```